# Zemax don't start (home-office link? )

Tags: windows-10, application-launch

For the 2nd time this year, I have to take my firm desktop computer to home.

After some days, Zemax (or OpticStudio 2016 ) just don't start.

- No license warning (and my Zemax Dongle is plugged in)
- No splash screen
- No error message
- just the mouse-cursor turn as if it was busy for 5 seconds and ... nothing. In the process-manager, I see Zemax for ~5 seconds and disapears.

I tried to re-install Visual C++ Redistributable, nothing worked.
I tried to use VPN as soon as possible after restart. (perhaps zemax-license tries to identify network ID, IP....)

After my last "home-office period", I came back in office, and after some days, Zemax started again.

Comment: Does Zemax install a service to handle the licence? (run `services.msc` to check)  If so can that service be restarted? Is there a "Zemax Licence Manager" program or similar on your computer? I assume you tried removing and plugging the dongle back in. You might need to talk to your firms IT and go through https://my.zemax.com/en-US/Knowledge-Base/kb-article/?ka=KA-01534 with them

Comment: What does your network Administrator have to say about it?  What about Zemax support?  **If your company does have a license server then your IT department will have to indicate the steps to remotely connect to it.**

Comment: @Mokubai : Thank you, I did not thought about that.
I started "services.msc", and did not fount any "Zemax License Manager".
But there is the "Sentinel LDK License Server". I tried to restart it, no change.

Comment: @Ramhound : We use USB dongle. 
It required to install a "sentinel server" on my machine, but restarting the computer or just this serivce does not solve the problem.

Comment: Contact your IT Administrator or Zemax  for support

Answer (score -1):

+1 on the license server, being at home puts you in your own network.These engineering solutions require a licensing server to say to your computer that it is ok to run the software hence its works when your at work.

You will need to vpn into your company network ,in particular be on the same subnet as the licensing server , which may or may not have security implications.

See this image https://downloads.zemax.com/zemax-portal/knowledge_articles/KA-01534/Images/Server-based-network.jpg

Comment: We use only dongle license, we never had server licenses. 

But Mokubai had a good ideas about this "license Manager" and I willl answer him.